# How can I declare and populate a class at the same time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have code like this:

```
public class test {
    public string aa { get; set; }
    public string bb { get; set; }
    public string cc { get; set; }
}

var a = new test {
    aa = "a",
    bb = "b"
}

var d = a;
d.cc = "c";
```

Is there any way for me to create class d and at the same time populate it. So for example the last two lines could be combined into one? Note that I want to avoid doing this with a constructor as sometime it will be different fields other than cc which I will populate.

please note my edit

```
var d = a;
```

Comment: What's wrong with doing it how you initialise `a`? If you really want it on one line, not just in one statement you could just put that on one line.

Comment: side note. you not creating class `d`, you creating instance of class `test`

Comment: As @Reniuz noted, also, it's setting it to the same instance that `a` refers to. i.e. change a property of `d` and you change `a`.

Comment: Also after this: `var d = a; d.cc = "c";` it actually changes `a.cc` property to `"c"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your new description of the problem, how about this:

Note that it changes `a` as well (same as your code), **it doesn't create a copy**. If you want a copy, go with Oded's solution.

```
public class test
{
    public string aa { get; set; }
    public string bb { get; set; }
    public string cc { get; set; }

    public test AlterTest(Action<test> alteration)
    {
        alteration(this);
        return this;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new test
    {
        aa = "a",
        bb = "b"
    };

    var d = a.AlterTest((t) => t.cc = "c");
}
```

I'd say this isn't as readable as your original code though (as you need to know what `AlterTest` does, which isn't a lot).

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. I will look into this now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the same way you have for `a`:

```
var d = new test {
    cc = "c"
}
```

This syntax is **not** using the constructor to pass in parameters, but is known as an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Whenever you create a new object from a class, a constructor gets called. There is no way to avoid this.

---

Update:

Now that it is clearer what you want to do, one way forward is to use a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) and use that as a basis for new objects:

```
public class test {

    public test(test o)
    {
      aa = o.aa;
      bb = o.bb;
    }

    public string aa { get; set; }
    public string bb { get; set; }
    public string cc { get; set; }
}

var a = new test {
    aa = "a",
    bb = "b"
}

var d = new test(a) {cc = "c"};
```

Comment: It *does* use the constructor. That code will call the parameterless constructor, then set the properties.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake then lost the internet connection so I could not immediately correct it. I changed the code now.

Comment: But what I need is to make d into a copy of a and then add some additional information.

Answer (score 3):

This line is not complile:

```
var d = test;
```

Initializers only works when crating object so in your case, only at this point:

```
var d = new test {
    cc = "c"
}
```

Msdn Doc about initializers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake then lost the internet connection so I could not immediately correct it. I changed the code now.

Comment: Anyway, it is not possible to use initializers on already initialized object. As far as i know there is no short syntax for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a constructor for the class and pass in the desired values

```
//Class constructor
public Test(string aa, string bb, string cc) 
{
    this.aa = aa;
    ...
}




var test = new Test("a","b","c")
```

Comment: I can't use constructors. Sometimes I want to update the field cc other times it might be one of many different fields.

Comment: without overloading the constructor for you various variables I am not sure what to suggest.